# Creating source and doc jars

Tags: maven

I've noticed something really cool about the m2eclipse plugin. When I try to view source on one of the class files included by Maven, at first it's unable to show it to me, but then in the background, it downloads a src JAR and a docs JAR. For my own projects how do I make and deploy these JARs alongside my binary JAR in my Maven repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by attaching the source and javadocs as part of your project build.  This [cookbook](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html) has the maven configuration needed for it.

Answer (score 1):

Maven Source Plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/usage.html